# Header in listview like instagram disappears

Tags: android, listview, instagram

I have a problem in listview. If I scroll list, all is good. But if I click on checkbox, header disappears. I checked, notifyOfChange() not started. I think this is due to the drawing of view. Who knows how to make the header is drawn in the last instance.
I use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    //the listview has only few children (of course according to the height of each child) who are visible
    for(int i=0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View child = list.getChildAt(i);
        MuscleViewHolder holder = (MuscleViewHolder) child.getTag();

        //if the view is the first item at the top we will do some processing
        if(i == 0)
        {
            boolean isAtBottom = child.getHeight() <= holder.headerLayout.getBottom();
            int offset = holder.previousTop - child.getTop();
            if(!(isAtBottom && offset > 0))
            {

                holder.previousTop = child.getTop();
                holder.headerLayout.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);

                holder.headerLayout.invalidate();
            }

        } //if the view is not the first item it "may" need some correction because of view re-use
        else if (holder.headerLayout.getTop() != 0)
        {
            int offset = -1 * holder.headerLayout.getTop();
            holder.headerLayout.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
            holder.previousTop = 0;
            holder.headerLayout.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I replace the code to the following

```
 if(!(isAtBottom && offset > 0)) {
                holder.setPreviousTop(child.getTop());
                if(itNotScroll){
                    holder.getHeaderLayout().offsetTopAndBottom(-holder.getPreviousTop());
                    itNotScroll = false;
                } else {
                    holder.getHeaderLayout().offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
                }
                holder.getHeaderLayout().invalidate();
            }
```

And yet, I did so, so that you can open only one element in expaned listview

Comment: Where's the definition of the methods `setPreviousTop` and `getHeaderLayout` that you created?